# SQL Server Select in if (subquery Result 0 rows use different statement)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 where I need to get a result with a subquery. In some case the subquery returns no results, and in this case I need these query with a null condition.

```
declare @InsID as int =12288 
declare @docentry as int = 28

select * 
from [Table1] a
where a.U_InsID = @InsID
  and a.DocEntry <> @docentry
  and a.U_ObjectType in ('1','5')
  and (month(a.U_Periode) in 
            (select max(MONTH(U_Periode)) 
             from [Table1] e 
             where e.U_InsID = a.U_InsID 
               and e.DocEntry <> @docentry 
               and (a.U_Status <> '2' or a.U_Status is null))
or (a.U_Periode is null and a.DocEntry <> @docentry and (a.U_Status <> '2' or a.U_Status is null))
)
```

In this query I get the "OR" result on any time... But I only want the result of the "OR" when the subquery result nothing...

Any ideas?

Best regards
Oliver

Comment: Can you consider rephrasing your question? it is unclear..

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is one Table. The query exclude the row that I'm working on and should return a result based on Max Date(Month) and if not there, there is a Row that has no Value in Period. and I need to get this.

In my first example the where "OR" get these sentence but on any time... I figuerd out a working solution a minute ago... but I geues this is not a nice one but it is working..

```
declare @InsID as int =12288 
declare @docentry as int = 31
declare @var as varchar(30)
--- get the max Month to U_InsID and not the actual Row '31'
set @var = (select max(MONTH(U_Periode)) 
    from [TABLE1] e 
    where e.U_InsID=@InsID
    and e.DocEntry <> @docentry 
    and (e.U_Status <> '2' or e.U_Status is null))

--- If there was no result do this....
if @var is null begin(
select * from [Table1] a
where a.U_InsID = @InsID
and a.DocEntry <> @docentry
and a.U_Periode is null and (a.U_Status <> '2' or a.U_Status is null)
)
end
else   ---- do this if there was a result...
select * from [TABLE1] a
where a.U_InsID = @InsID
and a.DocEntry <> @docentry
and month(a.U_Periode)=@var  and (a.U_Status <> '2' or a.U_Status is null)
```

And I'm looking for a smoother way of doing this instead using this IF... Else

I thought there should be a solution within the query itself...
best regards
Oliver